# How to solve underdetermined systems of polynomial equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I am trying to solve under determined simultaneous non - linear equations, where the variables are multiplied, but the power of the variables is always 1, is there a formal way doing it?

For eg: $x+y+z=6$, $xyz=6$

I was previously using reduced row Echelon form, but now that is less useful, is there a counterpart of Echelon matrix form for the above kind of equations?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No powers greater than 1 are used, the variables are multiplied that's all

Comment: Then you're in the realm of algebraic geometry. Solution sets will be algebraic curves, surfaces, etc. You can parameterize them.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo is there a name for solving them formally? some method name or something on which I can read on

Comment: I'm basically trying code a program, where if you give the equation it generates the family of possible answers, so I need something like a ready made formula

Comment: Take a look at [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gröbner_basis).

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but this is a really ambitious task in the general setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have too many unknowns, an option is to consider some of them as free parameters and solve for the remaining ones. In the given example, solve

$$\begin{cases}x+y+z=6,\\xyz=6\end{cases}$$ where $z$ is assumed to be known.

We can eliminate $y$ by multiplying the first equation by $xz$,

$$\begin{cases}x^2z+xyz+xz^2=6xz,\\xyz=6\end{cases}$$

which leaves us

$$x^2z+x(z^2-6z)+6=0,$$ quadratic in $x$.

This simple trick turns an indeterminate system into a determinate one, but the real problem of solving the determinate one remains.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With $$z=\frac{6}{xy}$$ we get
$$x^2y+xy^2-6xy+6=0$$ or
$$y^2+y(6+x)+\frac{6}{x}=0$$  so we get
$$y_{1,2}=-\frac{6+x}{2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{6+x}{2}\right)^2-\frac{6}{x}}$$
The solution is a curve.
And a Groebner bases is given by
$$6-6yz+y^2z+yz^2,x+y+z-6$$